# php login page logs me in and takes me to the home page even with the wrong username/password

Tags: php

I am building a login form using PHP and I noticed that even with the wrong username and password, I will still be logged in and directed to the home page. Infact, I do not have to type in anything in the field, all I have to do is click the submit button and it will automatically take me to my home page. This was not supposed to happen and I really need help. Please can anyone look at my codes and tell me the problem. Thanks a lot.
//my login.php file
Ok I have made changes to my codes and it is still the same result

```
    <?php

session_start();

#first if
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'conn.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['inpUsername']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['inpPassword']);

    //Error handerlers
    //Check if this input are empty
    #second if
    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location:login.html?login=empty");
        exit();
    }/*second else*/ else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        #third if
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location:login.html?login=error");
            exit();
        }/*third else*/ else {
            #forth if
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //de-hashing the password
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                #fifth if
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location:login.html?login=error");
                    exit();
                } /*fifth else*/ elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    //Log in the user here
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = var_dump($row['user_id']);
                    $_SESSION['u_first'] = var_dump($row['user_first']);
                    $_SESSION['u_last'] = var_dump($row['user_last']);
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = var_dump($row['user_email']);
                    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = var_dump($row['user_uid']);
                    //$_SESSION['user_pwd'] = $row['user_password'];
                    header("Location: ../Salon/Index.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}/*first else*/ else {
    header("Location:login.html?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

//my login.html form

```
<?php 
session_start();
//ini_set('display errors', 1);
//$monthname = strtolower(date('M'));
//include 'conn.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title> Login</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../assets/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="../assets/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>


<body>

   <form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <div id="msgPage" class="alert alert-info margin-10" role="alert">
        Please enter your information to log in.

      <div class="form-group">

        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inpUsername" placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inpPassword">Password</label>
           <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inpPassword" placeholder="Enter password">
         </div>

       <button type="submit" name="submit" class= "btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

//my connection page

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "forum";
$password = "12345";
$dbname = "discussion_forum";
//$table = "users";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: All the redirects point to the same page (../Salon/Index.html) although the query strings are different. Is that what you meant to do? It looks like you might want to redirect back to the login page on failures.

Comment: Oh thanks. I corrected that but it seems like it is not logging me in at all

Comment: `var_dump($row['user_pwd']);` shows what?

Comment: @Respawn you can ping me as I did for you here to answer what I asked. I moved out of the question now.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner Should I change $_SESSION['u_id'] =$row['user_id'] to $_SESSION['u_id'] = var_dump($row['user_id']);

Comment: Ok I have made corrections to my code by changing  $_SESSION['u_id'] =$row['user_id']  to $_SESSION['u_id'] = var_dump($row['user_id']). But it is still not logging in. This is really frustrating. Do you suggest that I should try to write a totally different code?

Comment: @Respawn What I asked wasn't to change what you were using, but by adding that under where you have those declared in order to see what the values are for them.

Answer (score 0):

Your links all take you to index, merely setting the `login` `$_GET` variable to either `error` or `success`. This is probably not the intended behavior, although you could use `$_GET['login']` to make some client-side display alterations (certainly don't use `$_GET` for login validation).

On your 'secure' page(s), what you'll want to do is check whether the `$_SESSION` variables that you defined are set up or not. If they are, you show the secure content. If they're not, you can either show an error message or redirect back to the login:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
  echo "Secure content";
}
else {
  header("Location: login.html");
}
```

Note that in your example, your 'secure' page is an `.html` file (`/Salon/Index.html`), meaning you won't be able to execute any PHP code there. You'll need to change it to a `.php` extension, and then update all of your links to reference this:

```
header("Location: ../Salon/Index.php?login=error");
header("Location: ../Salon/Index.php?login=success");
```

Comment: No probs. Can you please clarify further as to exactly what's not working? You've changed the extension, changed the references, and added the `$_SESSION` check? Have you confirmed that `$_SESSION` is actually getting set correctly? What are you seeing on the page?

Comment: I have changed the extension, references and I included the $_SESSION check in my login.html file but I can't login into my homepage this time. At first, I was  always logging in even when I did not put in any username and password but now, I can't login to my homepage(index.php) at all. It don't matter if the username/password is correct or not.